# Better debugger visualizer for JavaScript/Typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, typescript

When debugging C# code with visual studio and hovering over a variable the following popup is shown. I can directly see that the type of `myGreeter` is `ConsoleApplication2.Greeter`.

[image: C# debugger visualizer]

When debugging TypeScript/JavaScript code there is only displayed `{...}` which means that the variable is a JavaScript object:

[image: JavaScript debugger visualizer]

Can I somehow tell visual studio to show `obj.constructor.name` instead of just `{...}`?

**EDIT**

I have just seen that the Watch window does show the type:

[image: Watch window]

Can I show the type column also when hovering over a variable in code?

Comment: You probably can't do much more with the Visual Studio 2013 and you probably can't expect that someone will improve it as the Visual Studio 2015 (currently in preview version) addresses those issues, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx

Comment: @xmojmr: Thanks, I will have a look at Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do much more with the Visual Studio 2013 and you probably can't expect that someone will improve it as the Visual Studio 2015 (currently in preview version) addresses those issues, see [blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/…](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-typescript-1-3.aspx)
                    – [xmojmr](/users/2626313/xmojmr)